# I can only install gems for rails when appending the following param --source http://rubygems.org/

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

For example the following command does not work

**gem install multi_json -v '1.12.1**

But it works when I add **--source http://rubygems.org/**

**gem install multi_json -v '1.12.1 --source http://rubygems.org/**

By the way, I am using windows 8 and the command
**bundle install** does not work and I have to install the gems for rails one by one appending **--source http://rubygems.org/**

Anyway to fix this ?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does running

```
gem sources -a http://rubygems.org/
```

resolves your problem?

Comment: Nice man. Yes, it resolves it.
But I would prefer to make it work with https instead of http for security reasons.

Comment: Yes, it works with http
I would like a way to make it work with https

Comment: This is not related to your original question. You should ask another one

Answer (score 2):

Create a new file **~/.gemrc** and write this to it:

```
--- 
gem: --no-ri
sources: 
- http://gems.rubyforge.org/
- http://rubygems.org/
```